# How to import OAI or REST API url data in a specific content type node?

Tags: importing-exporting

I have a OAI/REST API url having thousand of records. How do I import these records in my content type node. Which module should I use? or I have to write custom module for this. Suggest some solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the Drupal migration framework and tools like migrate plus.

Comment: Migrate can do this. I’m doing it right now.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Kevin. Can you please suggest me some guide how to do it. I dont know how to use migrate module.

Comment: Thanks @ShawnConn. Your help is really appreciated. I've read all the documentation of migrate framework but not able to implement it practically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options depending on your needs. Do it once or frequently? Do you want to refresh the data/edit it.

Search on https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module for [Import/export](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module?f%5B0%5D=&f%5B1%5D=&f%5B2%5D=im_vid_3%3A64&f%5B3%5D=&f%5B4%5D=sm_field_project_type%3Afull&f%5B5%5D=&f%5B6%5D=&text=&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage+desc&op=Search)

- Migrate: importing. Using Migrate you have to code. You should start with [Migrate API](https://drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api) and especially [Migrating data from XML, JSON or SOAP source](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-source-plugins/migrating-data-from-xml-json-or-soap-source)
- Feeds: import once/interval/delete
- etc.

A different type is [external_entities](https://www.drupal.org/project/external_entities) which does keep a cached version of the remote content.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Migrate can import indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks for solution @Clemens . I am using Feeds module it helps me little bit for my needs. But I want to use migrate module can you suggest me some tutorial for this.

Comment: Using migrate API you have to code. You should start with https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api and especially https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-source-plugins/migrating-data-from-xml-json-or-soap-source

Comment: Thank you so much. Indeed it helped me

Comment: Nice to be of help. Please mark my answer as the answer please :-)